# Multiple Google Analytics: Universal Analytics tracking tags configured on the same website

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

We just noticed that our website has two  Google Analytics: Universal Analytics tracking tags configured.
Our website has the standard Google Analytics Javascript code snippet and also has a Tag manager Google Analytics Pageviews tag.

We understand this is an error and plan to fix it going forward. However, we want to know how this has affected our historical reporting?

I'm trying to understand specifically what metrics are being counted incorrectly and by how much.
For example - *pageviews* I believe are being double counted i.e. x2. Is it same for *Sessions* and *New Sessions* are these also being counted exactly twice? what about other metrics?

All of our GA data gets stored in our Data Warehouse and we then visualize our web analytics in a BI tool. If I can identify what was the impact of this misconfiguration then I can fix at least  some of the historical data in the data Warehouse.

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong on this, but I do not believe that a Tag Manager Universal GA Page View tag is the same thing as the Universal Google Analytics snippet you copy from within your GA admin section (e.g after creation).

I'm fairly certain GTM tags create a unique "tracker" every time they're fired, passing a unique `name` parameter. In a console you'd see something like this:

`ga("create", "UA-000000000-1", {name: "gtm1633733166"...})`

`1633733166` is a timestamp in unix.

Since your Universal Google Analytics tracking **snippet** automatically tracks pageviews and etc basic metrics, yes you are correct, adding a Universal Analytics **Page View tag** in addition will duplicate pageviews. I can't speak to sessions vs new sessions or other metrics

However, this happening also *should* have **tanked** your bounce rate.

So yeah...either way it's probably going to be a *pain*, but I'd look in your data lake for your bounce rate taking a nose dive or the unix timestamps generated by the GTM tag. Let's see if someone else can help us out and validate this.

Also, you'd probably know already if this was the case, but if for some reason the GTM tag was set up with Track Type: “Event” instead of "Page View" and given a *category* "Page View" you would not have duplicate pageviews, you would see an event called “Page View” being tracked separately.